# Uploading Images to Server not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name       = $_FILES['photo']['name'];  
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];  
        var_dump($_FILES);
        if(isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){ 
            var_dump($_FILES);     
                $location = '../images/';      
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully';

                }
            }       
        }  else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
    }

    ?>
<form action="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is my code to upload my images to my server im using iis and i get no errors but the image doesn't upload. I also what to upload the location to a mysql database but i just can't get it to work. I tried the upload along side a big form but it just clears all post's in my form and its getting annoying now haha two days trying to get this to work.
[Folder Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR61V.png)

Comment: Post your form code too!!

Comment: Do you see a message saying *`File uploaded successfully`*?

Comment: what is the error? there should be `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag

Comment: What about the write permission of the folder "images"?

Comment: I've added my form into the code and as you can see i put var_dump($_FILES) which will show if i submit with nothing in the upload but if i put a picture in nothing comes up at all.

Comment: the security to the temp folder and images is everyone has full access just so i didnt have to wurry about it

Comment: Im using this as a test to get image upload working as if i put this in my main form which submits to mysql it won't submit any data that is posted it can clears all the post fields and im stuck really

Comment: Please check your location folder. Give the right url for upload.

Comment: My location folder has noting in it and all permissions are open currently

Comment: show us folder structure

Comment: I've added my folder structure for you.

Comment: @alexwiggins try my answer below

Comment: '../images/' means one folder up from where your file is executing but your images is in the same location so change it to 'images/'

Comment: I have changed that @Mihai sorry i didnt put it in but still no luck

Comment: Change it to  '/images/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    //print_r($_POST);
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       echo  $name       = $_FILES['photo']['name'];  
        $temp_name  = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];  
        var_dump($_FILES);
        if(isset($name)){
            if(!empty($name)){ 
            var_dump($_FILES);     
                $location = '../images/'.$name;      
                if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location)){
                    echo 'File uploaded successfully';

                }
            }       
        }  else {
            echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but this still doesn't work no errors no nothing is there anything in IIS that could be messing this up.

Comment: I have done this but like i said there is no errors and i have php errors turned on. thank you for all your help i dont know if there just isnt a fix for this.

Comment: I have tryed this but still no luck :(

Comment: use action='' then try it.

Comment: this is tested code at my end. And it is working fine.

Comment: Are you using apache or IIS to test this

Answer (score 0):

My image folder structure: `C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\images`, I tried this and it is working:

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $name       = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){ 
            $location = 'images/';
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';
            }
        }
    }  else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
}
?>
<form action="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

I got the message: *`File uploaded successfully`* and also, I can find the image in that folder.

Comment: I've tryed this but i still have no luck could it be something to do with IIS at all because it doesnt come up with File Uploaded successfully it doesnt come up with anything.

Comment: there is no error just doesnt upload the file or say that it has done so

Comment: It may be because of permission issue.Please try give write permission to images folder and try.